# XPages height property of Radio Button Group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages

I couldn't find the Bootstrap property of RadioButton Group to reduce the space between table and radioButtonGroup.

[image: RadioButton Group Screenshot]

I tried to find with F12 then create my own class but with no succeess.

[image: My test Page looks like this.]

Any suggestion is appriciated.
Regards
Cumhur Ata

UPDATE: Code snippet of the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="ibm.com/xsp/core"; dojoParseOnLoad="true" dojoTheme="true" xmlns:xc="ibm.com/xsp/custom"; xmlns:xe="ibm.com/xsp/coreex"; xmlns:bx="openntf.org/xsp/bootstrap">
<xp:this.resources>
    <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.ExtLib"></xp:dojoModule>
    <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.Loading"></xp:dojoModule>
</xp:this.resources>
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="openDocument" formName="STAF">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:table styleClass="table-condensed table-sm" style="width:100%!important;">
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label id="label1" value="Label"> </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>:</xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText1" styleClass="form-control input-xs txtEditBox" value="#{viewScope.result1}"> </xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label id="label2" value="Label"> </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td>:</xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText2" styleClass="form-control input-xs txtEditBox" value="#{viewScope.result2}">
            </xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label id="label3" value="Label"> </xp:label>
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td> </xp:td>
        <xp:td> 
            <xp:radioGroup id="finished" value="#{sessionScope.finished}" rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable();}" styleClass="sameLineLeft">
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Evet" itemValue="1" id="selectItem25"> </xp:selectItem>
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Hayır" itemValue="0" id="selectItem26"> </xp:selectItem>
            </xp:radioGroup>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:label id="referansno" value="Label"> </xp:label>    
        </xp:td>
        <xp:td> </xp:td>
        <xp:td>
            <xp:inputText id="inputText3" styleClass="form-control input-xs txtEditBox" value="#{viewScope.result3}"> </xp:inputText>
        </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
</xp:table>
```

Comment: Could you post your source code...

Comment: <xp:radioGroup id="ToplamTutarVarmi"
      value="#{document1.ToplamTutarVarmi}"
      rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable();}" style="height:10.0px!important;">
      <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Evet" itemValue="1"
       id="selectItem5">
      </xp:selectItem>
      <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Hayir" itemValue="0"
       id="selectItem6">
      </xp:selectItem>
     </xp:radioGroup>

Comment: I sent only radioButtonGroup code? Is there any code i should send? Because it's in a table.

Comment: Please send the whole code including the table.

Comment: I tried to send whole page code but it's too long to send it? I will try to send it part by part

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoParseOnLoad="true"
 dojoTheme="true" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
 xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" 
 xmlns:bx="http://www.openntf.org/xsp/bootstrap">
<xp:this.resources>
  <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.ExtLib"></xp:dojoModule>
  <xp:dojoModule name="extlib.dijit.Loading"></xp:dojoModule>
 </xp:this.resources>
  <xp:this.data>
  <xp:dominoDocument var="document1" action="openDocument" formName="STAF">

 
  </xp:dominoDocument>
 </xp:this.data>

Comment: <xp:table styleClass="table-condensed table-sm" style="width:100%!important;">
    
   <xp:tr>
    <xp:td>
     
    <xp:label id="label1" value="Label">
  
 </xp:label></xp:td>
    <xp:td>:</xp:td>
    <xp:td>
     
     
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" styleClass="form-control input-xs txtEditBox" value="#{viewScope.result1}">
     </xp:inputText></xp:td>
    
    
    
   </xp:tr>

Comment: <xp:tr><xp:td>
     
    <xp:label id="label2" value="Label">
  
 </xp:label></xp:td><xp:td>:</xp:td><xp:td>
     
    <xp:inputText id="inputText2" styleClass="form-control input-xs txtEditBox" value="#{viewScope.result2}">
     </xp:inputText></xp:td></xp:tr><xp:tr><xp:td>
 <xp:label id="label3" value="Label">
  
 </xp:label></xp:td><xp:td></xp:td><xp:td>

Comment: <xp:radioGroup id="finished" value="#{sessionScope.finished}"
  rendered="#{javascript:document1.isEditable();}"
  styleClass="sameLineLeft">
  <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Evet" itemValue="1"
   id="selectItem25">
  </xp:selectItem>
  <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Hayır" itemValue="0"
   id="selectItem26">
  </xp:selectItem>
 </xp:radioGroup></xp:td></xp:tr><xp:tr><xp:td>
 <xp:label id="referansno" value="Label">
  
 </xp:label>

Comment: </xp:td><xp:td></xp:td><xp:td>
 <xp:inputText id="inputText3" styleClass="form-control input-xs txtEditBox" value="#{viewScope.result3}">
     </xp:inputText></xp:td></xp:tr></xp:table></xp:view>

Comment: From up to down you can copy one by one then paste them into a XPages then it will work..
I have created my own CSS to reduce distance between table and editbox or any other design elements but I did not include it to my question.

Comment: Hint for the future: It would be better to update/edit a question and paste the source code in there instead of using a lot of comments...

Comment: +1 to Georg's comment. It's impossible to read that code in a bunch of comments. I've edited the original question to add the code from your comments. As you can see, it's much easier to read and understand. Please edit your questions in the future if you are adding additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem, overwriting the bootstrap default margins, by creating your own `custom.css` file with the following piece of CSS code:

```
.radio {
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Notice: You have to include this file in your xpage!

Hint: I am not experienced in `bootstrap` and perhaps this job could be done in a better way (e.g. [Change the default Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/), ...)

Comment: The point that i don't know is the name of the Bootstrap property which i have to put them into my Custom Style Sheet. 

I will try yours :)

Thank you,